# How to draw and save straight lines in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, draw, lines

I need to be able to draw straight lines in AngularJS to visually separate the screen into multiple areas. These lines / coordinates need to be saved into and then retrieved from the database later on. Editing these lines, such as re-positioning or deleting, etc. would also be necessary.

[image: straight lines on the screen]

Comment: have a look at this [codepen](https://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/lhajz) you can save the info on svg and retrieve it however you like

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".